# VSO Create Work Item on Failure - work item cannot be opened

Tags: build-automation, azure-devops

I have an issue with Visual Studio Online. I have automatic build enabled, with the `Create Work Item on Failure` option checked. However, if a build fails, the newly created work item cannot be opened.

If I click on the link from the notification email or I try to find it by ID, the page shows the following error message:

> Invalid argument value. Parameter name: typeNames

After a few refreshes, this error message changes into

> Unknown server error

I can find the created work items via queries though, but still I can't open them, I only see a blank page or one of the errors mentioned above.

In case of trying to edit a work item (`Edit selected work item(s)...` option), I got this in a popup:

```
k/<.error@https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20160209T154641/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=MIkPf9V9olbPKZDYhX0CnlVPFxxBqIzzD-zEJlJxbwk1:22:618
ur</n.prototype.beginGetWorkItemTypes/h@https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20160209T154641/_scripts/TFS/min/WorkItemTrackingJsCore?v=jVPYRLgy_xKN2NuFBC6W2evM9wo5OpfnDilaHhA5pDs1:22:41311
nt@https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20160209T154641/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=MIkPf9V9olbPKZDYhX0CnlVPFxxBqIzzD-zEJlJxbwk1:22:1236
a/</<@https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20160209T154641/_scripts/TFS/min/TfsPresentationCoreJs?v=WNelSDEdKqBUSM9-eflsRAx7fn2i7dJ_n12zkAHbTOA1:22:1624
nt@https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20160209T154641/_scripts/TFS/min/TfsPresentationCoreJs?v=WNelSDEdKqBUSM9-eflsRAx7fn2i7dJ_n12zkAHbTOA1:22:893
a/<@https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20160209T154641/_scripts/TFS/min/TfsPresentationCoreJs?v=WNelSDEdKqBUSM9-eflsRAx7fn2i7dJ_n12zkAHbTOA1:22:1263
i.Callbacks/l@https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20160209T154641/_scripts/TFS/min/basejs:14:35816
i.Callbacks/s.fireWith@https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20160209T154641/_scripts/TFS/min/basejs:14:36641
w@https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20160209T154641/_scripts/TFS/min/basejs:14:73475
.send/t/<@https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20160209T154641/_scripts/TFS/min/basejs:14:79367
Session Id: f3cf7f05-6757-4e18-b1a4-dc9346eee712
```

I noticed one more thing, the newly created items' type is not simply `Bug` or `User Story` (as for the rest of the work items), but `Microsoft.VSTS.WorkitemTypes.Bug` or `Microsoft.VSTS.WorkitemTypes.UserStory`.

I tried several variations, but the result is always the same:

- create a `User Story` instead of a `Bug` (with the `Agile Process Template`)
- create a `Product Backlog Item` with `Scrum Process Template` (different VSO solution, different user account)

Anyone has a suggestion what I might miss?

**update**
I use the default Aglie Process template with no customization.
The work items cannot be opened  by any team member, they all get the same error. It also occurs on different machines / browsers.

Also, I added the error in the popup, which is displayed if I try to edit the work item.

Comment: I assume you haven't done any process template customisation?  Is everyone having trouble opening the Work Items?  Have you tried on a different computer/browser?  Maybe a cache thing?

Comment: @rerwinRR I extended the question with the replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed now. Please refer to the feedback from Microsoft for details:

> In Sprint 94, a problem was inadvertently introduced, which caused the
>   build system to create work items with an invalid value for the “work
>   item type” field. This invalid value renders those specific work items
>   unable to be opened at all. In Sprint 95, the issue was fixed to make
>   sure created work items are valid. In a future sprint, we intend to
>   ship code which will go back and fix up any invalid work items, so any
>   historical work items affected by this issue can be opened again.